# Why create-react-app cant find my Sass variables

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

I create react app with create-react-app and setup the file structure like that:

```
src/
 -index.js
 -main.scss
 pages/
  -somepage.js
  -somepage.scss
 styles/
  -_variables.scss
```

**index.js**

```
import './main.scss';
...
```

**main.scss**

```
@import './styles/variables.scss';
```

**_variables.scss**

```
 $primary: #000;
```

**somepage.js**

```
import somepage.scss
```

**somepage.scss**

```
selector {
 property: $primary; <-- sass can't find that
}
```

Any ideas please?
Thank you.

Comment: For this you need to ensure somepage.scss is called after variables.scss.

Comment: still no answer??

Answer (score 1):

You need this...

npm install node-sass

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Can you try this ?

Comment: did u try to import _variables.scss file inside somepage.scss ?

Comment: No because I want to use _variables.scss inside all my scss files and not only in one file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import './styles/variables';
@import './pages/somepage';
```

You could import all stylesheets in your *main.scss* and then all you need is `import './main.scss';` in *index.js*. You also don't have to to specify the suffix.

[Finding the File](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#finding-the-file)

Comment: It means that every page I create I need to add import inside main.scss ?
Not too much ? :O